# Remove files after upgrade to 5.24.4?

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from version 5.24.1 to 5.24.4 (Joomla) i get the

> System Status: Critical File
>   'C:\wamp\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\bower_components/google-code-prettify/styles/demo.html'
>   presents a security risk and should be deleted. Same for:
>   C:\wamp\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\bower_components/qunit/addons

Can I remove these files?

Answer (score 4):

yes, its safe to remove the folder as it was part of security advisory.

see:  [CIVI-SA-2020-08: XSS VIA JS LIBRARIES](https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2020-08)

Comment: Thank you, i did not see that link. I have removed the file and the folder without any errors.

Comment: FYI, the advisory has been amended to clarify that you may still need to remove the files manually after the upgrade, depending on exactly how you do the upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I understood, but critical warnings after the  upgrade (new session application) where new for me. I try always to install every version seperated, but now i had to do some in one upgrade.